# What is aggregation in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, aggregation

I am trying to learn aggregation in SSAS,

I belive when we create a cube it generates dimensions and facts it generates all the possible combinations already then,
What exactly happens when we create Aggregation in SSAS?

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Generally not all aggregations are created, but instead the "SSAS engine creates the aggregations based on an internal cost-vs.-benefit algorithm."  Think of the aggregations as group by's in SQL that are saved on disk, as defined by your aggregation design.

If all possible aggregations are saved we can get database explosion causing the aggregations to be larger than the source data.  This can actually make query performance worse.

Comment: Having only a link is not an answer - please either summarize the content, or post this as a comment :)